# Notification for FIN/ACK using python socket

Tags: python, python-sockets

I have a basic implementation of a TCP client using python sockets, all the client does is connect to a server and send heartbeats every X seconds. The problem is that I don't want to send the server a heartbeat if the connection is closed, but I'm not sure how to detect this situation without actually sending a heartbeat and catch an exception. When I turn off the server, in the traffic capture I see FIN/ACK arriving and the client sends an ACK back, this is when I want my code to do something (or at least change some internal state of the connection). Currently, what happens is after the server went down and X seconds passed since last heartbeat the client will try to send another heartbeat, only then I see RST packet in the traffic capture and get an exception of broken pipe (errno 32). Clearly python socket handles the transport layer and the heartbeats are part of application layer, the problem I want to solve is not to send the redundant heartbeat after FIN/ACK arrived from server, any simple way to know the connection state with python socket?

Comment: What's wrong with handling an exception?

Comment: I happens to late, I want to know as soon as the FIN/ACK arrived, I don't want to wait for X seconds since last heartbeat, not sure why it is not exposed in API some way, sounds pretty basic

Comment: At first glance TCP looks more basic than it actually it and especially than it happens.